# Adding CSS class to Global Overlay in Angular 9 at runtime

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I am creating an Angular 9 web-app that changes theme as per the choice of the user, akin to [material.angular.io/](https://material.angular.io/). To handle the resulting transparent background of mat-select, I then referred to the 
 Angular material [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) , to add my custom theme classes in the global overlay container as follows.

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(overlayContainer: OverlayContainer) {
    overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('purple-amber');
    overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('indigo-pink');
    overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('pink-bluegrey');
    overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('purple-green');
  }
 }
```

However, the mat-select element always has the last added class (in this case, purple-green) as it's overlay, regardless of what theme I select. How could I solve this? Is there a way through which I could add the theme to the classList through a component's TypeScript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have 2 themes: "purple-amber" and "indigo-pink", those themes change by clicking a button.

You need call a function when those button are clicked.

some-component.html:

```
...
<button mat-raised-button (click)="applyPurpleTheme()">Purple Amber</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="applyIndigoTheme()">Indigo Pink</button>
...
```

some-component.ts

```
...
constructor(private OverlayContainer: OverlayContainer) { }

applyPurpleTheme() {
    const overlayContainerClasses = this.OverlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList;
    // I always remove other theme classes
    if (overlayContainerClasses.contains('indigo-pink')) {
        overlayContainerClasses.remove('indigo-pink');
    }

    overlayContainerClasses.add('purple-amber');
}


applyIndigoTheme() {
    const overlayContainerClasses = this.OverlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList;
    // I always remove other theme classes
    if (overlayContainerClasses.contains('purple-amber')) {
        overlayContainerClasses.remove('purple-amber');
    }

    overlayContainerClasses.add('indigo-pink');
}

...
```

Comment: This worked like butter, thank you. Any idea why we have to first remove the class to the list, then add a new one? It's not working if I don't remove the class.

Comment: Because cause a "conflict" whit classes whit overlay panel.

If you inspect an overlay you can see something like this:
`<div class="cdk-overlay-container your-theme-name"></div>`.

If the overlay has more that one theme classes maybe the last one it is applied.